# Regarding automatically disconnection from socket runnning on ec2 instance

Tags: php, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpws

I am creating a php  web application. It have socket feature for chat purpose. 
I set port *9999* as *TCP* port. I ran Socket on this port(Using private IP) and it  run successfully. Then I  created client script to connect to this socket. 
At my local machine it is working absolutely perfect(When server is running at local machine). Then I moved code to  EC2 instance and trying to connect, it automatically disconnected within 1 second. For debugging purpose, I printed resource. Here is  outcome :

```
2017-11-12 11:33:34 | HYBI Response SENT!
2017-11-12 11:33:34 | User has been added to echo
[DEMO] 97 connected 
Resources : Array
(
[0] => Resource id #13
[1] => Resource id #97
)
Resources : Array
(
[0] => Resource id #13
[1] => Resource id #97
)
2017-11-12 11:33:34 | Socket accepted
Resources : Array
(
[0] => Resource id #13
[1] => Resource id #97
[2] => Resource id #98
)
[DEMO] 97 disconnected
```

You can see here resource ID 97 connected and within a sec it got disconnected.

If there is any missing step OR any setting I need to do?